# Comparing mailing vs internal traffic for a goal completion (adding product opinion)

Tags: google-analytics, analytics, web-analytics

Our main product opinion aquisition channel are our mailings, that are sent after a purchase. Additionally, within Your Account panel, in past purchases there is an option to review a product a client bought.

I would like to compare how many percent of reviews does the functionality in Your Account provides. Adding a review is set as a goal, but I can't compare them as I would compare traffic channels, because Your Account page is not a channel. What would be the correct way to do that?

I have also done a sequence which includes users, step 1 is Page - Your Account, step 2 is Goal Completion per user more and equal 1. I'm not sure if I approached this problem correctly.